# How are questions sorted?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have asked some question on Stack Overflow and a few of the question are answered and some were not.

How is a question sorted on the site? Does it depend on the priority, the reputation scored by the asker, the question or the number of tags?

Comment: Depends on the header, for example, when looking at [tagged questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) they can be sorted by "newest" or "active" amongst others. Is your question specifically this or how to improve the chance of receiving an answer?

Comment: Yes how to improve the chance of receiving quick response and answers

Comment: You can start by looking at [ask] - I had a quick look at [one of your unanswered questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25074048/1324033) and it just states that "it doesn't work" more or less, it doesn't include what you have tried, or anything about what does happen. Generally I am more inclined to help with questions that demonstrate an attempt at self solving the problem

Comment: Thanks for the link and I tried hard to fix that error but could not get the output what I expected

Comment: I suggest that you try to update that question then with information about what you tried, what output you were getting, and what you expected to happen

Comment: Yes I will follow this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions can be sorted in a number of ways:

- by age - newest first.
- by votes - those with most votes first.
- by activity - those that have been recently edited or answered first.
- by links (the frequent tab) - those that are linked to the most first.

The can also be filtered:

- bounty - those with the bounty and sorted by the bounty nearest to expiring.
- unanswered - those with no answer or no upvoted answer first.

Questions on the home page are the ones most recently modified filtered by the tags you are most interested/active in.

The reputation of the asker is not used to decide whether to display a question or not.

If you want people to answer your question then you need to make sure:

- it states exactly what the problem is, what you expect and what you actually get.
- it contains the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem.
- it has the appropriate tags.
- it has a good title that describes the problem.
- it's written in English with few spelling and grammatical errors.

The [How to Ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page has more information on this.

These things make it easy for experts in the area to find and then understand your question. If they can do that then there's a good chance they'll answer.